# How do display angularjs validation feedback in a div

Tags: angularjs

I am new to `angularjs`.

It seems out of the box `angularjs` shows validation feedback in bubbles in realtime.

I've managed to find a way to show the errors on `defocus`.

Is there a way, however, to only present the feedback on a `div` at the top of my form instead of in bubbles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bubbles you see are HTML5 standard bubbles.

To valid entirely your form yourself, you'll have add a `novalidate` property on your `form` and handle the form validation through an `ng-submit` `form` custom function.

More info : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit
and http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms for custom form validation

Comment: Awesome! that worked. However, my form is still being submitted to the server even if its not valid. My js is below.
 $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.signin_form.$valid) {
            alert('');
            // Submit as normal
        } else {
            $scope.submitted = true;
            return false;
        }
    }